# How to listen to oggdemux gstreamer failures?

Tags: gstreamer, ogg, opus, gstreamer-1.0

I wrote a gstreamer app to convert from opus audio to raw audio. If I feed bad audio (just random bytes) to the pipeline, the pipeline gets stuck and /i don't receive an error message on the message bus.

I'm listening to the error messages flowing through the pipeline, but not getting an error code to indicate the failure. The gstreamer debug logs indicate the demux failed though, I can see the following in the logs:

```
0:00:00.021614679 22541       0xe5b190 WARN                oggdemux gstoggdemux.c:4609:gst_ogg_demux_send_event:<oggdemux0> No chain to forward event to
0:00:00.021656681 22541       0xe5b190 WARN                oggdemux gstoggdemux.c:2433:gst_ogg_demux_sink_event:<oggdemux0> EOS while trying to retrieve chain, seeking disabled
```

The following is an app sample that I wrote:

```c
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/gstbin.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappsrc.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappsink.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static GMainLoop *loop;

FILE *file = NULL;
size_t bytesRead = 0;

typedef struct _CustomData
{
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstAppSrc *app_source;

  guint sourceid; /* To control the GSource */

} CustomData;

static gboolean push_data(CustomData *data)
{
  GstBuffer *gbuffer;
  GstFlowReturn ret;

  char buffer[1024];

  gbuffer = gst_buffer_new_and_alloc(sizeof(buffer));
  GstMapInfo info;

  bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), file);

  gst_buffer_map(gbuffer, &info, GST_MAP_WRITE);
  memcpy(info.data, buffer, bytesRead);
  gst_buffer_unmap(gbuffer, &info);

  if (bytesRead > 0)
  {
    //g_print("Pushing %d\n", (int)bytesRead);
    /* Push the buffer into the appsrc */
    g_signal_emit_by_name(data->app_source, "push-buffer", gbuffer, &ret);
    return TRUE;
  }
  else
  {
    g_print("file complete\n");
    gst_app_src_end_of_stream(data->app_source);
    return FALSE;
  }

  gst_buffer_unref(gbuffer);
}

static void stop_feed(GstElement *source, CustomData *data)
{
  if (data->sourceid != 0)
  {
    g_print("Stop feeding\n");
    g_source_remove(data->sourceid);
    data->sourceid = 0;
  }
}

static void start_feed(GstElement *source, guint size, CustomData *data)
{
  if (data->sourceid == 0)
  {
    g_print("Start feeding\n");
    data->sourceid = g_idle_add((GSourceFunc)push_data, data);
  }
}

static gboolean bus_call(GstBus * bus, GstMessage * msg, gpointer user_data)
{
  switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg))
  {

  case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
    g_print("End of stream\n");
    g_main_loop_quit(loop);
    break;

  case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
  {
    gchar *debug;
    GError *error;

    gst_message_parse_error(msg, &error, &debug);
    g_free(debug);

    g_printerr("Error: from %s %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME(msg->src), error->message);
    g_error_free(error);

    g_main_loop_quit(loop);
    break;
  }
  default:
    break;
  }

  return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc,
         char *argv[])
{
  CustomData data;
  memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));
  GstBus *bus;
  guint bus_watch_id;

  /* Initialisation */
  gst_init(&argc, &argv);

  loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

  GError *error = NULL;


  data.pipeline = gst_parse_launch("concat name=c ! filesink location=program.wav appsrc name=src_00 ! oggdemux ! opusdec ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw,format=S16LE,channels=1,rate=16000 ! queue ! c.", &error); 

  if (!data.pipeline)
  {
    g_printerr("Pipeline could not be created. Exiting.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  data.app_source = (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST((gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(data.pipeline), "src_00")), GST_TYPE_APP_SRC, GstAppSrc));
  g_signal_connect(data.app_source, "need-data", G_CALLBACK(start_feed), &data);
  g_signal_connect(data.app_source, "enough-data", G_CALLBACK(stop_feed), &data);

  /* we add a message handler */
  bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(GST_PIPELINE(data.pipeline));
  bus_watch_id = gst_bus_add_watch(bus, bus_call, NULL);
  gst_object_unref(bus);

  file = fopen("junk.wav", "rb");

  /* Set the pipeline to "playing" state*/
  g_print("Now playing");
  gst_element_set_state(data.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  /* Iterate */
  g_print("Running...\n");
  g_main_loop_run(loop);

  /* Out of the main loop, clean up nicely */
  g_print("Returned, stopping playback\n");
  gst_element_set_state(data.pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

  g_print("Deleting pipeline\n");
  gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(data.pipeline));
  g_source_remove(bus_watch_id);
  g_main_loop_unref(loop);
  return 0;
}
```

I would have expected that the demux failure would follow to the message bus, but it is not. How can I listen to such errors ?

I've tried with other pipelines that uses `decodebin` and I get the error messages on the message bus. The following pipeline works as expected:

```c
gst_parse_launch("concat name=c ! filesink location=program.wav appsrc name=src_00 ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw,format=S16LE,channels=1,rate=16000 ! queue ! c.", &error);
```

**GStreamer version: 1.8.3
OS: Ubuntu 16.04**

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be resolved in Gstreamer 1.14. After updating I now get an error message on the message bus:

```
Message: Error: from oggdemux0 Could not demultiplex stream.
Error Code: GST_STREAM_ERROR_DEMUX
```